# cuda : Is shared memory always helpful?

Tags: c, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

When I read the programming guide, I got the feeling that shared memory will always improve the performance, but it seems not.
I have two functions:

```
const int Ntimes=1;

__global__ void testgl(float *A, float *C, int numElements){

    int ti = threadIdx.x;
    int b0 = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;

    if (b0+ti < numElements){
        for(int i=0;i<Ntimes;i++){
            A[b0+ti]=A[b0+ti]*A[b0+ti]*10-2*A[b0+ti]+1;
        }
        C[b0+ti] = A[b0+ti]*A[b0+ti];
    }
}


__global__ void testsh(float *A, float *C, int numElements){

    int ti = threadIdx.x;
    int b0 = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;

    __shared__ float a[1024];

    if (b0+ti < numElements){
        a[ti]=A[b0+ti];
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if (b0+ti < numElements){
        for(int i=0;i<Ntimes;i++){
            a[ti]=a[ti]*a[ti]*10-2*a[ti]+1;
        }
        C[b0+ti] = a[ti]*a[ti];
    }
}

int main(void){

    int numElements = 500000;
    size_t size = numElements * sizeof(float);

    // Allocate the host input
    float *h_A = (float *)malloc(size);
    float *h_B = (float *)malloc(size);

    // Allocate the host output
    float *h_C = (float *)malloc(size);
    float *h_D = (float *)malloc(size);


    // Initialize the host input
    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++){
        h_A[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        h_B[i] = h_A[i];
    }

    // Allocate the device input
    float *d_A = NULL; cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, size);
    float *d_B = NULL; cudaMalloc((void **)&d_B, size);
    float *d_C = NULL; cudaMalloc((void **)&d_C, size);
    float *d_D = NULL; cudaMalloc((void **)&d_D, size);


    //Copy to Device
    cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);  
    cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    // Launch the Vector Add CUDA Kernel
    int threadsPerBlock = 1024;
    int blocksPerGrid =(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
    
    testgl<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_C, numElements);

    testsh<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_B, d_D, numElements);

    // Copy the device resultto the host 
    cudaMemcpy(h_C, d_C, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(h_D, d_D, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


    // Free device global memory
    cudaFree(d_A);
    cudaFree(d_B);
    cudaFree(d_C);
    cudaFree(d_D);

    // Free host memory
    free(h_A);
    free(h_B);
    free(h_C);
    free(h_D);

    // Reset the device and exit
    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

If `Ntimes` is set to be 1, `testgl` costs 49us, and `testsh` costs 97us.
If `Ntimes` is set to be 100, `testgl` costs 9.7ms, and `testsh` costs 8.9ms.

I do not know why it's more than 100 times longer.

So it seems the shared memory helps only when we want to do a lot of things in device, is that right?

The card used here is **GTX680**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The benefits coming from the use of shared memory are architecture-dependent (you are not mentioning which architecture you are targeting). In Fermi and Kepler, shared memory is made by the same circuitry as L1 cache and can be thought of, at all intents and purposes, as a controlled cache. As you know, data from global memory are moved to L1 cache to enable faster accesses to subsequent memory transactions on the same data, but they can be evicted by other global memory data if there is not enough space. Shared memory is a way to guarantee that data of your interest reside on chip.

Comment: Thank you. my architecture is Kepler.

Comment: Can you measure the performance using the modified code [here](http://pastebin.com/NbgH0X83) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**shared memory will always improve the performance**

Thats not true. It depends on the algorithm. If you have a perfectly coalesced memory access in the kernel and you are accessing the global memory just once it may not help. But if you are implementing suppose a matrix multiplication where you need the partial sums to be held then it will be useful.

It will be also helpful if you are accessing the same memory location more than once in the kernel it will help in this case since the shared memory latency is 100 times less than the global memory because its on-chip memory.

When you analyse that the kernel is **bandwidth limited** then its a good place to think if there is a scope of using the shared memory and increase the performance. Its also better strategy to check the occupancy calculator to check if the usage of shared memory is going to affect the occupancy.

**shared memory helps only when we want to do a lot of things in device** ?

Partial Yes. Shared memory helps when we want to do a lot of things in device.

In your case in the above kernel, as you are accessing the global memory more than once in the kernel it should help. It will be helpful if you can provide the complete reproducer to analyze the code. Also it will be helpful to know the card details you are running on.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a beginner and please forgive me if I ask some silly questions: How can I know whether my kernel touches the limit of bandwith?

Comment: Basically, there are 2 performance limiters. 1) Memory bandwidth limited 2) Instruction limited. The memory bandwidth kernels perform less operation per byte fetched from the global memory. You can also study `nvprof` profiler from nvidia site which should help you to determine the performance limiter. Is this the code you are running how you are measuring the time. I modified your code to measure the timing and pasted [here](http://pastebin.com/NbgH0X83). I am running on tesla K20c. You may get slightly better since your card has PCIe 3.0 and tesla k20c has PCIe 2.0.

Comment: You can see that in my system shared memory performance is better in both the cases.

Comment: Thank you. I find that my time cost is much larger than your case. With Ntimes=100, it costs me ~9ms, and Ntime=1 costs ~0.2ms. As you mentioned my card has even better PCIe and it's expected to be better. I'm a little confused.

Comment: Actually it shouldn't matter.. pcie 3 or 2 matters only in host to device ande device to host transfer.. did u use modified code I pasted ?? Am not sure you are measuring it right or not..

Comment: Maybe this is due to the difference between Tesla and GeForce, I don't know. But it's really big different performances.

Comment: With Ntimes = 100  k20c takes `0.19ms` and with Ntimes=1 k20c takes `0.06ms`. The timings I posted are in `ms`. Let me remind you that `cudaEventElapsedTime` gives in `ms`. Anyways thats separate issue. Lets not discuss that here. If you think the above answer explains the solution you can accept the answer. If not you can wait someone more experienced person to answer.

Comment: @HuaYe, how are you compiling the code? GTX680 performance is very similar to K20, so your results should not be that different from Sagar. Make sure you are not using debug options, without -G (debug) on my GTX680 the timing for Ntimes=100 is about .2 ms (with -G, is't about 9ms, like yours)